# Converting to Currency format

Tags: java

```
                System.out.print(toLn+toFn+toStr+toC+toSt+toZ+fromLn+fromFn+fromStr+fromC+fromSt+fromZ+beforeN+d+ship+bsize+msg+"\n");
                //add info to addOrder
                double test = manager.addOrder(toLn, toFn, toStr, toC, toSt, toZ, fromLn, fromFn, fromStr, fromC, fromSt, fromZ, beforeN, d, ship, bsize, msg);

                beforeN = false;


                totalField.setText(Double.toString(test));
            }
        }
    }
```

The trouble i am having is that the value that is brought forth by totalfield.setText(Double.toString(test)); is a value, lets say 52.0. Its displaying 52.0 but what i want it to do is display $ 52.0 in the TextField. Any quick suggestions as to how to do it?
    }

Comment: You should include only a code example that is relevant to your question. As it stands, it has way too many irrelevant lines of code.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have removed as much of the code that is not required.

Answer (score 0):

totalField.setText("$ " + Double.toString(test));

Comment: @user1873746 if this answer is the solution to your problem, you should upvote it and accept it.